# Erlang - Spawn MFA vs Spawn Fun

Tags: erlang, spawn

I have been trying to work with Programming Erlang , Version 2 ( Joe Armstrong's book). I am trying to solve the first problem in the Chap 13.

As a solution to the problem - I came up with this -

```
-module(errorhandle1).
-export([my_spawn/3,loop/1,test_func/0]).

my_spawn(Mod,Fun,Args) -> 
   %SpawnedPidRef = myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args),
   %spawn(?MODULE , loop , [myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)]).
   spawn(fun() -> loop(myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)) end).

myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args) ->
   statistics(wall_clock),
   spawn_monitor(Mod,Fun,Args).

loop({SpPid,SpRef}) ->
   io:format("Created Pid is : ~p~n",[SpPid]),
   receive
      {makeError,Msg} -> 
          SpPid ! Msg,
          loop({SpPid,SpRef});
      {'DOWN',SpRef, process,SpPid,Why} ->
          {_, Time1} = statistics(wall_clock),
            io:format("Down"),
            io:format("Process spawn time = ~p microsecond ~n",[Time1])
end.

test_func() ->
    receive
        X -> 
           list_to_atom(X)
    end.
```

The above code works and produces the desired output (first step is to solve the problem). Then I commented the line and came up with the following program , which is exactly same as the above one but , I use spawn/3 function instead of a spawn/1 and I dont seem to get the desired output.

```
-module(errorhandle1).
-export([my_spawn/3,loop/1,test_func/0]).

my_spawn(Mod,Fun,Args) -> 
   %SpawnedPidRef = myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args),
   spawn(?MODULE , loop , [myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)]).
   %spawn(fun() -> loop(myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)) end).

myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args) ->
   statistics(wall_clock),
   spawn_monitor(Mod,Fun,Args).

loop({SpPid,SpRef}) ->
   io:format("Created Pid is : ~p~n",[SpPid]),
   receive
      {makeError,Msg} -> 
          SpPid ! Msg,
          loop({SpPid,SpRef});
      {'DOWN',SpRef, process,SpPid,Why} ->
          {_, Time1} = statistics(wall_clock),
            io:format("Down"),
            io:format("Process spawn time = ~p microsecond ~n",[Time1])
end.

test_func() ->
    receive
        X -> 
           list_to_atom(X)
    end.
```

Steps to execute the above module:
    c(errorhandle1).
    Pid = errorhandle1:my_spawn(errorhandle1,test_func,[]).
    Pid ! {makeError,test}.

Can some please help me with my understanding of the usage of spawn/3 and spawn/1 ?

Thanks,
Sathish.

Comment: Can you say what the desired output is and what you're getting that's different?  That will help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: This is the question from the book -   Write a function my_spawn(Mod, Func, Args) that behaves like spawn(Mod, Func, Args) but with one difference. If the spawned process dies, a message should be printed saying why the process died and how long the process lived for before it died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
spawn(fun() -> loop(myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)) end).
```

is not an equivalent of

```
spawn(?MODULE , loop , [myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)]).
```

in the second case `[myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)]` is a parameter of function `spawn/3`. The value of a parameter is evaluated before a function call. It means the call `myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args)` is made before the call to the `spawn/3` outside of a new process in the original one. You can see it as this code

```
SpawnedPidRef = myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args),
spawn(?MODULE , loop , [SpawnedPidRef]).
```

the equivalent with `spawn/1` would look like

```
SpawnedPidRef = myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args),
spawn(fun() -> loop(SpawnedPidRef) end).
```

Now you can see the difference. Only `loop(SpawnedPidRef)` is actually done inside a new process. But in your first version you perform `loop(myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args))` in a new process. You can see it like

```
spawn(fun() ->
        SpawnedPidRef = myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args),
        loop(SpawnedPidRef)
    end).
```

which is very different code. (See the last two blocks. The last one is you first version and other one is your second version.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Hynek ,your response certainly helped me. I will try to restructure my code so that I can use spawn/3 instead of spawn/1. If you do have some pointers , I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just make some exported function which contain `loop(myspawn_helper(Mod,Fun,Args))`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue when I run your code, except the test should be Pid ! {makeError,"test"}. so the second field of the tuple is a list, not an atom.

Comment: The idea here is to make the function test_func , throw an error and let the process monitoring this function handle the error and print the time the process was alive.  I have presumed that every one had the book "Programming Erlang" ; but now I have added the question in the book as a comment to the question asked.